# Releasing COM references used in PowerShell RunSpace

Tags: powershell

My application hosts PowerShell and adds COM object references via `RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable()`.  After adding the variables and calling Invoke on some PowerShell code, the COM objects don't get released properly.  How can I force all COM references (including those for temporary references returned by calling the COM object model) to be released by PowerShell and the .NET runtime?  I tried calling

```
    object o = rs.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable(name);
    if (o != null)
    {
        rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable(name, null);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
    }
```

on all the variables, as well `PipeLine.Dispose()`, `Runspace.Close()`, and `GC.Collect()`, but it didn't help.

Comment: You might try `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` although I wonder if there is some other script/command that is holding onto a reference besides the variable you null out.

Comment: That didn't help either.  I'm not sure what other script/command could be involved -- the behavior occurs even if the PowerShell code doesn't call these objects (i.e., the variables are set but never used).

Comment: I figured it out -- when storing the variables, temporary references were getting created: rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("name", obj.subobj).  If I instead store the return value of obj.subobj in a variable and release after calling SetVariable, everything works as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Keith's tip, I tracked this down.  When storing the variables, temporary references were getting created:

```
RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("name", obj.subobj)
```

If I instead store the return value of obj.subobj in a variable and `ReleaseComObject` on the local variable after calling `SetVariable`, everything works as expected.